# How to solve h,k in terms of A,B,C,D,E with standard linear algebra method?

Tags: linear-algebra

How to solve h,k in terms of A,B,C,D,E with standard linear algebra method?
$$2Ah + Bk = -D$$
$$Bh + 2Ck = -E$$

Comment: Are all of $A,B,C,D,E$ square matrices of the same size? What are $h$ and $k$? Scalars, vectors or square matrices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using [Schur complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement#Application_to_solving_linear_equations) ([another reference](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~jean/schur-comp.pdf) on the internet)?

Comment: Yes, Please solve it

Comment: @Victor It's already solved in the Wikipedia entry I linked to, isn't it?